# How to create a group of users (roomates) within one product (property) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a question on a platform I'm developing in Ruby on Rails 5.2.

I have an Owner model which is the owner of properties/property. The owner will post a property so that users (in this case roomates) can share the same property/house/department, etc.

I have Owners and I have Users (both tables are created using devise):

`Owner.rb`:

```
class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties
end
```

`User.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   #Theres nothing here (yet)
end
```

This is where the magic happens. `Property.rb`:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner
    has_many :amenities
    has_many :services

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :amenities
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
    mount_uploaders :pictures, PropertypictureUploader
    validates :amenities, :services,  presence: true 

    scope :latest, -> { order created_at: :desc }

end
```

How can multiple users  share a property? I'm aware that it will have a many-to-many association but I'm a bit confused  how to connect these relationships so when the owner posts a property it will display something like:

```
Property available for: 3 users
```

And then begin to limit users until it completes the amount of users available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like your average many to many assocation:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tenancies, foreign_key: :tenant_id
  has_many :properties, through: :tenancies
end

class Tenancy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :property
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tenancies
  has_many :tenants, through: :tenancies

  def availablity
    # or whatever attribute you have that defines the maximum number
    max_tenants - tenancies.count
  end
end
```

You can restrict the number of tenants with a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).

Comment: While you could call the model `UserProperty` it kind of sucks as it tells you nothing about the what the model represents. Tenancy, Occupancy, or Lease are far better choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join table, called `users_properties`. This table will have a `property_id` and `user_id`. You'll then have the following in your `properties` model:

```
has_many :users_properties
has_many :users, through: :users_properties
```

Read more about it here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Hayden! Thanks for your answer this clears me up on the ID'S for each tables <3